# Multi-party Real-time GPS tracking for IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, gps, real-time

I am looking for a way to do real-time tracking of multiple vehicles (with iphones) at a time.

Instamapper is close to what I need - I can install the app to run in the background of driver IOS devices and then capture the GPS through the instamapper API.  However, the updates are not quick enough - only 1 every 10 seconds.  I believe I would like to sample one time per second or more.

I ran across this today - http://www.vworkapp.com/ - It is a paid app, looks interesting, although I was concerned because there did not seem to be many existing customers using the product based on the app store reviews.

I like Glympse for my personal use, but they do not have an API yet.

Any suggestions on existing IOS products that accomplish this functionality?  If not, any source code that is close so I can make required tweaks?

Answer (score 0):

It's not likely that you really need that much info about vehicles other than your own.

Most apps which show movement in maps interpolate between points of much coarser data. This is why your car often appears to go the right direction for a moment, even if you go the wrong way when following GPS. Movement displayed is predicted by previous data, and corrected when new data contradicts predictions.

Go ahead and update your own device a bunch, cause the battery drain is your only factor to consider. For everyone else, calculate velocity (that's speed and direction together), and use it to update your info on their vehicles smoothly.